# How to define started activity when relaunching Android application?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

I am fairly new to Android, and am currently working on a simple XMPP Client. A user should be able to log in, and should be notified whenever an XMPP message arrives. It should be possible to access an overview of all messages that arrived during the current session.

When launching the application, a LoginActivity is started, prompting the user to fill in his or her credentials. If the right credentials are provided, a background service is started:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationService.class);
startService(intent);
```

On startup, the notification service adds a packet listener to the XMPP connection and requests to be running in the foreground. The users is prompted with a notification caused by this foreground request ("Ongoing"). Now I have provided a second activity called XMPPClientActivity, showing all messages that are received during the session and a simple logout button. When opening the application from within the "Ongoing" notification, the XMPPClientActivity is started because the notification is defined like this:

```
xmppIntent = new Intent(this, XMPPClientActivity.class);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, xmppIntent, 0);
NotificationCompat.Builder xmppBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
xmppBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
// Notification details
startForeground(id, xmppBuilder.build());
```

When opening the application from the home screen however, the LoginActivity is opened again. Of course I want the XMPPActivity to be started, but I can't seem to figure out how this should be done. I have been looking into binding an activity to a service, but I'm unsure if this can be of any help. What is the right way to do this?

Comment: Do you want them to only ever have to login one time unless they click "logout" button?

Comment: You could always have the app launch to a landing page Activity.  There, in your onCreate, check if you are already logged in (perhaps some in-memory value) and, if not, startActivity the login activity (and finish the landing page Activity).  After login, set the in-memory value and startActivity the landing page activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do, as I understand you issue, is use [ShaeredPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref). Create a preference like "loggedin" and set a `boolean` variable to `true` the first time they log in. Now you can set this to `false` when they click the "logout" `Button`.

When the `Activity` is started you can check the `SharedPreference` before calling `setContentView()` and if the value is `true` then `finish()` the `LoginActivity` and open your other `Activity`.

The link to the docs I provided has a good example of creating, opening, and editing `SharedPreferences`