# How to know if my activity was open by Android?

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to run some function only when my app is first open. When the activity is cose and return it, the functions are runiing againg. I want only to run one time, when thr app is open.

The problem is: When I run my app and this first activity is open. Then I left this activity to another with a intent and the finish() method. When i return to this first activity, the code run again. I dont want this code run again, only time I open the app.

Comment: What else would open your app?

Comment: I talking about my activity. Some other activity open my activity. It is my first activity from the app. I want that some functionr run only when it is first open.

Comment: [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17974904/how-to-define-started-activity-when-relaunching-android-application/17975105#17975105)

Answer (score 2):

A great way to run something only once is by saving a boolean flag in `SharedPreferences`.

(in your Activity)

```
public static final String PREFS_FILE = "prefs";
public static final String FIRST_OPEN_PREF = "firstopen";

...

SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_FILE, MODE_PRIVATE);
boolean activityWasOpenBefore = settings.getBoolean(FIRST_OPEN_PREF, false);

if(activityWasOpenBefore) {
    //Do something if my activity was open before
} else {
    //Do something if this is the first time the activity is open

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(FIRST_OPEN_PREF, true);
    editor.commit();
}
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Comment: I dont want to run it only once. I want it run every time the app is open. The problem is: when I run my app, I quit that first activity, and return to this activity and this functions run again.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a class that uses SharedPrefences .

When the app is first created save a value into SharedPreferences that states that.

Any other time your app opens simply check whether or not the value is present in SharedPreferences.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want a static variable.

Whilst the process running your app is alive the static variable will be kept. If the VM dies, the state of the static is lost.

Since there isn't any guarantee of when or even if the VM will be destroyed by the system whilst your activity is in the background, it isn't fool proof, but might be ok for what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit confusing, since you state that you want code to run only once, but in another answer that suggested using `SharedPreferences` for this, you wrote in a comment

> I dont want to run it only once. I want it run every time the app is
>   open

If you put code in `onCreate()` of your starting (root) activity, that code will run each time the Activity is started. If you put code in `onResume()`, then the code will run each time your activity is started, or brought to the foreground.

Comment: Thats the problem. I dont want the code run each time the activity is started. I want the code run only the first time this activity is started. Some time I quit this activity and return again. I dont want the code run this times.

Comment: explain what you mean by "quit and return again". This isn't clear.

Comment: I run my app and this first activity is open. Then I left this activity to another with a intent and the finish() method. When i return to this first activity, the code run again.

Comment: Don't finish your Activity when you go to the next one. Then, when the user comes back, `onCreate()` will not be run. You need to somehow be able to tell the difference between the first time and the following times. You'll need to adjust your architecture a bit to accommodate this.